# JPA @ManyToOne - EntityNotFoundException or null value?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Under the hood a persistence Provider like EclipseLink or Hibernate uses `find()` or `getReference()` to load entities when we call getter methods of a `ManyToOne` annotated field?

`find()` returns `null` if EntityNotFound

`getReference()` throws an `EntityNotFoundException`

So what should getters do in the case the Entity is not found?

Answer (score 0):

> Under the hood a persistence Provider like EclipseLink or Hibernate
>
> ```
> uses find() or getReference()
> ```
>
> to load entities when we call getter methods of a ManyToOne annotated field?

Hibernate does not call find or getRefernce behind the scenes. Those methods are used for the client to locate either an entity or a Proxy.

If you have a `@ManyToOne` association, Hibernate already knows how to fetch the parent entity since, behind the scenes, the JPA `@ManyToOne` is just a Foreign Key.

But Hibernate already knows the value of the FK when you navigate the association because the original `ResultSet` that loaded the child entity contained the value of the FK too.

However, it's not mandatory for Hibernate to go to the DB because the loading cycle is as follows:

1. The first-level cache is searched for the entity that you need
2. If nothing is found in the 1st-level cache, Hibernate tries to locate it in the 2nd-level cache
3. If the entity is still not found, then a secondary query will be issued since the association must be LAZY.

So, in reality, there is no need for an `EntityNotFoundException` when we are navigating a FK because a child cannot reference a non-existing parent record. If you didn't use a FK and you had such an inconsistency in your database, then Hibernate will indeed throw an exception. But that would tell you that your data modelling design is probably broken.

Comment: Thanks indees for the answer ! I'm using EclipseLink in one of my project and I have no FK costraint enforced and when I call getMyEntity on a ManyToOne association I simply get a null value.Is this consistent with JPA spec ?

Comment: You should ask the EclipseLink team about it. I don't think that JPA specifies what should be the standard outcome for a navigating a non-existing association.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad !